# Universal covering

Tags: differential-geometry, covering-spaces, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $M=S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^n$ with the metric $g=-d\psi^2+q$, where $d \psi^2$ is the standard metric on $S^1$ and $q$ is the euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I know that the universal covering of $S^1$ is given by

$$\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1, t \mapsto e^{2 \pi i t}$$

Is is then correct that the universal covering of $M$ is given by the Minkowski space-time

$$ \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^n, (t,x) \mapsto (e^{2 \pi i t}, x)$$
?

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823566/product-of-coverings-is-a-covering-of-product-space) with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546438/any-homeomorphism-is-a-covering-map) Note that $\pi_1(\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R)\cong \pi_1(\Bbb R^n)\times \pi_1(\Bbb R)=0\times 0=0$ by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291311/the-fundamental-group-of-a-product-is-the-product-of-the-fundamental-groups-of-t).

Comment: As far as I see, from this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823566/product-of-coverings-is-a-covering-of-product-space , I already obtain that my assumption is correct. Why do I need the third part of your comment?

Comment: "Yes" (your assertion is correct).

Comment: Thank you for the answer!